# Overflow and flexbox not working well together

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am working on a web app. I use a NavBar and on some pages I have to center the content (vertically and horizontally).

To make the navbar + the rest of the content occupy 100% of the page (more if the content is big) and to make the centering work, I do:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Without the flexbox, a scroll appears on my page and I can scroll just past the navbar + the content is not centered - it will be after I scroll down. And this happens even when the centered content is just a single little `<span>`. So I thought the flexbox is the answer here, easy. But I stumbled upon another problem:

I sometimes display card-like divs - rounded borders with a header which is filled with a color. Background color fill + `border-radius` don't play well together (basically the rounded edges disappear as the color overflows the borders), so I use `overflow: hidden`.

The problem that I encountered is that if I do three things:

- I set the flexbox for `html` and `body` tags like I've shown above
- I set `overflow: hidden` for my div
- I add more content to the div - so much, that it doesn't fit on the page and a user would have to scroll it vertically

then the scroll doesn't appear and the content inside my card is cut/truncated just before the page ends - so no scroll. And no content.

**This is the codesandbox example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-pare-1qokr.

To see what I mean try either:

- removing the flexbox props from `html` and `body` (you can leave the height and the margin)
- removing the `overflow: hidden` from `.card`

If you do, then boom, scroll appears and the content is no longer truncated.

And I cannot proceed without any of them because I either:

- lose the ability to not have the scroll when having just the navbar and some `<span>`
- or
- lose the rounded edges, because the card's color will overflow (I didn't show it in the example, but I use it)

The `.navbar` and `.center` classes are there just to show that:

- this is how I basically define the navbar in my project (although here I defined the height as fixed pixels, normally I don't do that so I cannot easily, I guess, calculate the height for the rest of the content)
- the `.center` class is used by me to center the whole content below the navbar, when I want it to be centered

So finally my question is: can I somehow preserve the ability to have `flexbox` defined for my `html` and `body` tags, have `overflow` defined for some long divs **and** make it so the div's content isn't truncated when it becomes too long - basically the page would render a scroll then?

P.S If the solution would be not to use flexbox to make the centering without the scroll work - perfect for me, if you guys know how to do it without flexbox (as without the flexbox, my issue with truncated div content gets solved)